# CPAN 'crashing' on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: perl, ubuntu-12.04, cpan

I am trying to install perl modules using CPAN but CPAN seems to be crashing. It says there is an update that I can install (I'm running v1.960001) but after trying to run, it exits back to the command prompt:

```
cpan[1]> install CPAN
Going to read '/home/ubuntu/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz'
............................................................................DONE
Going to read '/home/ubuntu/.cpan/sources/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz'
  Database was generated on Tue, 04 Jun 2013 14:08:21 GMT
..............
  New CPAN.pm version (v2.00) available.
  [Currently running version is v1.960001]
  You might want to try
    install CPAN
    reload cpan
  to both upgrade CPAN.pm and run the new version without leaving
  the current session.


..............................................
ubuntu@ip-10-166-105-207:/home/www/cgi-bin$ sudo cpan
Terminal does not support AddHistory.

There seems to be running another CPAN process (pid 10592).  Contacting...
Other job not responding. Shall I overwrite the lockfile '/home/ubuntu/.cpan/.lock'? (Y/n) [y]
```

When I try to get back into CPAN, it says that it's already running.

This happens when I try to update CPAN or install modules (like JSON).

Does anyone have any clues what might be going wrong?

Comment: Where is the `crash`?

Comment: Is that the system cpan that came with Ubuntu? Are you running it with sudo or have you been running it with sudo?

Comment: So, what happens when you say yes to overwriting the lock file?

Comment: I believe it is the one that came with Ubuntu and I am running it as sudo.

If I say yes and remove the lockfile, it goes back into CPAN (not upgraded) and if I try to install anything, it just closes again

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem on 14.04, and fixed it by adding a swapfile on the system, using the instructions located at: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04